# Why is my object property returning undefined?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a project component that displays my projects on my portfolio website. I want to make it reusable so I can pass different values (projects) to the this.

I'm creating an object containing all of the properties of the project and then passing it as a prop to the component.

eg:  let portfolioProject = [
{
title: 'Portfolio Website',
description: 'My portfolio website',
img: Portfolio,
gitHub: 'project'
}
]

When I pass the whole object to the component and log it in the console it works fine. When I try to add a property when logging it the value returns undefined.
eg: project.title

Does anyone know what may be causing this issue?

*I have shortened the code for this example to make it more clear.*

```js
  let portfolioProject = [
    {
      title: 'Portfolio Website',
      description: 'My portfolio website',
      img: Portfolio,
      gitHub: 'https://github.com/gavinwalsh1996/flight-entertainment-system'
    }
  ]
  
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
    <div className="App" id={theme}>
        <Header theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme}/>
        <Home />
        <About />
        <Projects heading={heading}/>
        <Projects project={portfolioProject}/>
```

```js
function Projects({heading, project}) {

  const {title, description, img, gitHub} = project
  console.log(project.title) // Title property returns undefined




  let buttonValue1= 'Live App';
  let buttonValue2= 'Learn More';
  let FlightEntLink = 'https://github.com/gavinwalsh1996/flight-entertainment-system';
```

Comment: You need to iterate over the array while mapping the value present inside otherwise you will get undefined only

Comment: Yes, try `const {title, description, img, gitHub} = project[0]` or `<Projects project={portfolioProject[0]}/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `portfolioProject` is an Array of objects.

What you have to do to be able to display each project is to make a loop to browse each project of this variable, so you will have access to the properties.

For example :

```js
// Here I renamed the project to projects (Because it's a list of project)
function Projects({heading, projects}) {

 return (
 <>
// Below we are looping through each element of the Array
 {projects.map((project)=>{

  const {title, description, img, gitHub} = project
  console.log(project.title) // Title property returns a string

  return(<p>{title}</p>)

  })}

 </>
)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are defining portfolioProject as an arrey and then accessing it as object, this should solve it

```js
  let portfolioProject = {
      title: 'Portfolio Website',
      description: 'My portfolio website',
      img: Portfolio,
      gitHub: 'https://github.com/gavinwalsh1996/flight-entertainment-system'
    }
  
  
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
    <div className="App" id={theme}>
        <Header theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme}/>
        <Home />
        <About />
        <Projects heading={heading}/>
        <Projects project={portfolioProject}/>
```